# C++11/14 features for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I`m C++ developer for windows phone. Is it possible to use the latest c++ compiler (msvc 14.0, shipped with Visual Studio 15) to compile windows runtime components for windows phone 8.1 winRT? I really need the c++11/14 features included. Is it going to be something like v140_wp81 platform toolset? If not could you provide me with some explanation or some links to information related to this issue.

Comment: Try it and find out....?

Comment: Can`t choose anything like platform toolset v140_wp81 is visual studio 15, so there is no easy way to do this. I tried to change the compiler manually but i always failed at some point (some libraries missing or link time errors). As there is no straight way to do this it looks more like a hack. I would be really grateful if someone who tried and succeeded would share some experience on that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual C++ 2015 cannot be used to build apps or components for Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted?  This is the correct answer.

Comment: I'am not a downvoter, but as far as I know if you have Windows Phone SDK installed then you can compile for WP 8.1. But it will not give you the latest compiler features from Visual C++ 2015. So with VS2015 we will have to compile universal apps for Windows 10?

Comment: @marcinj:  Correct.  From the Visual Studio 2015 IDE, you can use the Visual C++ 2013 toolset and libraries to build for Windows Phone 8.1.  You can use the Visual C++ 2015 toolset and libraries to build for Windows 10.  You cannot use the Visual C++ 2015 toolset and libraries to build for Windows Phone 8.1.